# Automatically append ssh flags for gcloud cli

Tags: ssh, sdk, gcloud, environment, flags

I am working on a project with multiple envs on gcloud

2 of the envs have a central 'bastion' server so when logging into the central filesystem I have to ssh twice

A colleague discovered that in order to stay logged in to the final shell:

- `--ssh-flag="-o ServerAliveInterval=30"` has to be appended to both ssh commands

As we speak this ssh flag is in my shell history, it is not such a big problem but I like having a config for each env so I would really like to be able to automatically append this ssh flag per env-config

Is there a way? I know there are ways to adjust settings once you are inside the shell on a per-session basis (can't really remember where I saw it, but direct ssh shell commands whilst in session) so I guess this might also be fine, but not sure and good enough.

Really though I am looking for ways to automatically include the flag in the gcloud command via `gcloud config configurations`, but merit other ideas.

bash aliases or functions are kind of obvious to me already, and are a last resort

Comment: Have you already tried to use shell aliases to avoid typing this flag?
Could you please also elaborate a bit more on this part: *"to automatically append this ssh flag per env-config"*?
As you know, you can use `ssh` command with your private key from `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`, so maybe there's a suitable config option.

Comment: @FaridShumbar you can use the standard ssh command? I have been using `gcloud compute ssh` this whole time!

Comment: @FaridShumbar So I can just use the normal ssh command and then define such settings in my ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: What you are referring to is possible per [SSH connections to Linux VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh#third-party-tools_1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatically append an `--ssh-flag` to ssh commands in Gcloud CLI, you can use the private key as described in [SSH connections to Linux VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh#third-party-tools)

Comment: Farid, thanks for the answer, sorry I didn't reply
Because of restrictions with  our hosting provider I don't think that I am able to connect with basic ssh (as far as I am aware). `gcloud compute config-ssh` throws a permissions error about setting metadata

Comment: @ScottAnderson I think it would be best to create a new post about the permissions error as it looks like another question

Comment: But this is not solveable - the hosting provider on my project is a 3rd party only contactable through my management. I cannot change settings through the gcloud settings myself. Request has already been made to access via ssh but they are not doing anything about it